# How can one check that user does not select from many2one field in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, erp

I want to hide field and show it after user select from Many2one field so I use (attrs={'invisible': [('Many2one_field_name', '=', 'default_val')]), but i do not know what is the default value of Many2one field so can any one help me please ?

Comment: The default value is the value of the field (in form view) when you create a new record.

Comment: @Kenly Please could you explain more detailed ?

Comment: `default` attribute is used to set the default field value when declaring the field. users can set default values using the interface, the default values set by users can be found under `Settings/Technical/Actions/User-defined Defaults`.What do you mean by the `default value of Many2one field`?

Comment: @Kenly I mean the value that many2many field has when it isn't be selected

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to all how help me.

The default value of many2one field (the value of the field when it isn't selected) is `False` and my code work when I write:

```
attrs={'invisible': [('Many2one_field_name', '=', False)]}
```